# Date string not recognized as valid DateTime

Tags: flutter, dart

I am storing a date string in SharedPreferences as `2022-9-14 19:34`, but this is not recognized as DateTime when using

```
 DateTime dt1 = DateTime.parse(_inicio);
        print("fecha······· ${(dt1)}");
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid date format
2022-9-14 19:34
```

What I need is to show the date string as `14-09-2022 19:34`

EDIT

The date string is saved as follows:

```
var hoy = DateTime.now();
                        var ano = hoy.year.toString();
                        var mes = hoy.month.toString();
                        var dia = hoy.day.toString();
                        var turno = "";
                        var fechaHora = ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+_timeOfDay.format(context).toString();
```

And _timeOfDay is the picked time from TimePicker.

Comment: Can you include how you are saving with DateFormat

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, just added to my question as edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2022-09-14 19:34` is one of the valid case. So you need to add zeros where there is a single digit (month in this case)

[image]

But a better solution would be to store `DateTime.now().toString()` directly in shared-preferences. You could also use a package like [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) to format the date in your choice of format.

Since you're using time as well from timepicker, you could use DateTime constructor will all 5 values like this:

```dart
new DateTime(year, month, date, hour, minute).toString();
```